What is the general expectation for the availability/retention of the experimental data?
A statement from this answer has caught my eye:

certainly you can't be expected to hold onto old datasets in perpetuity

So far, this is exactly what I have been striving to do, to the best of my ability. It is often impractical, it consumes a lot of resources (time being the most costly one), and pragmatically, I am near-certain I would never ever have any use for much of this data.
However, ethically, I consider it to be a part of the burden associated with the job: no one likes chasing apocryphal datasets and results, and sometimes new ideas require revisiting decades old work. Assuming the lack of convenient options for archival, what is the reasonable retention time for the experimental datasets? 10 years? 15? 30?
What would be the guiding principles to determine it?

I think this rather depends on the type of the data set, but in the current age where many data repositories are freely available, why not publish the data if feasible?

@Anyon: biological, medical or psychological data often has strong privacy implications. (Fun fact: maybe you collected data ten years ago under then-legal privacy and data protection rules, which nowadays are not OK any more... but you may need to hold on to the raw data ten years beyond the last publication based on them, which might only have happened recently.)

Is it really that impractical? In my experience, storage prices have been dropping faster than how fast the rate at which I produce research data grows. This means that the older the data, the cheaper it is to hold on to it, to the point where it's cheaper to just keep it indefinitely than to think whether and what could be deleted. A year's worth of my raw research data from 15 years ago is just a couple dozen gigabytes, and that's what I produce in just a few days nowadays.

@TooTea buying personal storage is easy.  Getting storage hosted by a university (unless it fits into a framework they already have, and many aren't at all flexible) can be much harder, and it's the uni's data.

I have several boxes of 5" floppies from way back. They are available. They have been retained. Getting the data off them might be a slight problem...

@Anyon Well, to give an example - Zenodo's size limit for a dataset is 50 GB or so. This is somewhat typical for the freely available data storage, it's not too hard to store up to a ~terabyte, but past that, it tends to be problematic. And, as other commenters have pointed out, there are other potential problems with off-site storage.

@TooTea Depends on your threshold for practicality, I suppose. Perhaps the most important in my specific case is that much of this data was acquired using some old, now-phased-out hardware; we have better devices and procedures now. But if anyone's to ever access it, I need to maintain the entire relevant stack. Even without that, procuring a mere 10T worth of storage with at least a single back up in another physical location can involve a whole bunch of red tape. We also seemingly got on the big data trend early, so 10 years ago it was already ~0.5TB/year, and grew slowly since.

@Lodinn Hence the "if feasible" part. That said, sometimes publishing/retaining some processed data (reduced for size, anonymized, etc.) is the best that can be done. That's part of what I meant by "depends on the type of the data set". Practical and pragmatic considerations should be factored into the expectations in my opinion.

@Lodinn As far as archival goes, I'd just store the raw files and forget about the rest of the stack. That's probably the most cost-efficient option, because with a very slim chance of the data ever being needed again, it makes more sense to potentially have to pay thousands to rebuild the stack at that point if needed than to maintain it all the time. 1T of archival storage (e.g. S3 Glacier archival tiers, no endorsement) can be had for just a few €/$/£ per year, so some 100T costs a tiny fraction of the yearly budget of a typical lab.

I remember what Mrs. Grill taught us in 7th grade:  never throw out he primary data

You should consult the policies of your institution and your department. Some require lodging data in an archive. It might not be perpetual but it is close.

The job of archiving stuff is best done by professional archivists. There are various archives that focus on preserving data and making them available in a legal and ethical way, e.g. ICPSR in the USA, Gesis in Germany, DANS in the Netherlands, etc. Go to the website of the archive that is relevant to you, and you will find instructions on how to submit your datasets.
That way there is a legal department that takes care of all legal problems that may arise. If 40 years from now nobody can read the dataformat of your dataset, then the archive has people specialized in reading ancient file formats. If you are no longer alive 40 years from now, the archive still exists and your data is still available. So this is not something you should try to do yourself.

A good starting point would be your funder's requirements. In Germany for example the German Research Foundation (DFG) funds a lot of university research. Its guidelines for handling of research data state that data should be stored for at least 10 years (see their guidelines).
In fact, I have had a lot of projects funded by the DFG, but they never checked on our research data management so far. Also, although you have to include a statement about data handling in proposals, my project partners rather often do not take this very seriously, and also the reviewer reports never mentioned anything critical about it. So for all practical purposes, my take is that we are still working towards a standard best practice.

UKRI on the UK also specifies 10 years.
